# Tearadata Connection Error In IBM Datastage

Tags: java, websphere, teradata, datastage, ibm-infosphere

Whenever I run the DS job I am getting following issue

"Error loading connector library cctera12.dll. The specified module could not be found.
(CC_LoadedConnector::loadLibrary, file CC_ConnectorFactory.cpp, line 1,536)"

But cctera12.dll this library is present in dscomponents and also mentioned that path in system path.

Please help to solve this issue , thanks .

Answer (score 0):

here are few steps you can follow.

1. ensure that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is having link to the DSComponents/bin folder.
2. With your #tags i assume that you are facing issue with Teradata database so make sure that the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is updated with Teradata home location. If its oracle db `ORACLE_HOME` location should be present in library.
3. you may need to restart your datastage server and services